# Converting dict to dataframe of Solution point values & plotting

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

[image]

I am trying to plot some results obtained after optimisation using Gurobi.
I have converted the dictionary to python dataframe.
it is 96*1
But now how do I use this dataframe to plot as 1st row-value, 2nd row-value, I am attaching the snapshot of the same.

Please anyone can help me in this?

```
x={}
for t in time1:
    x[t]= [price_energy[t-1]*EnergyResource[174,t].X] 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient='index')
df
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a line chart from dictionary - Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458666/create-a-line-chart-from-dictionary-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pandas.DataFrame(data=x.values())` to properly create a pandas DataFrame while using row numbers as indices.

In the example below, I have generated a (pseudo) random dictionary with 10 values, and stored it as a data frame using [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) giving a name to the only column as `xyz`. To understand how indexing works, please see [`Indexing and selecting data`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html).

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Create a dictionary 'x'
rng = np.random.default_rng(121)
x = dict(zip(np.arange(10), rng.random((1, 10))[0]))

# Create a dataframe from 'x'
df = pd.DataFrame(x.values(), index=x.keys(), columns=["xyz"])
print(df)
print(df.index)

# Plot the dataframe
plt.plot(df.index, df.xyz)
plt.show()
```

This prints `df` as:

```
        xyz
0  0.632816
1  0.297902
2  0.824260
3  0.580722
4  0.593562
5  0.793063
6  0.444513
7  0.386832
8  0.214222
9  0.029993
```

and gives *df.index* as:
`Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')`

and also plots the figure:
[image]